# Post array with Ajax but PHP gets string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tabledit

I'm posting several variables from Ajax to PHP and one of them is an array. However PHP sees a string instead of an array. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Ajax string seen in Firefox Dev console:

Form data:

```
id=106
category_name=windows
category_friendly_name=Windows+product
show_for_ids=4
show_for_ids=7
show_for_ids=10
show_for_ids=12
is_admin_only=0
action=edit
```

Request payload

```
id=106&category_name=windows&category_friendly_name=Windows+product&show_for_ids=4&show_for_ids=7&show_for_ids=10&show_for_ids=12&is_admin_only=0&action=edit
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST['show_for_ids']);
```

Outputs:

```
string(2) "12"
```

Using [Multi-select plugin for TableEdit](https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit/commit/4a90afff0da1a13cf85bf76b25ef5d69316acfc3) and [Jquery-multi-select](https://github.com/mysociety/jquery-multi-select/issues)

What am I missing?

Comment: For array, your data must be `show_for_ids[]=4 show_for_ids[]=7` etc. Currently next value just ovewrites previous. probably your forgot `[]` in `name` attribute.

Comment: @charlietfl The title says AJAX and there's an `ajax` tag.

Comment: Show how you create the payload. If using an object for `data` it should get serialized properly by jQuery so you receive an array

Comment: Thank, I had to modify `jquery-tabledit` to get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @u_mulder comment I fixed the issue by modifying the code provided on [Github](https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit/commit/4a90afff0da1a13cf85bf76b25ef5d69316acfc3) for `jquery-tabledit` line 140.

I changed

```
input = '<select class="multiSelect tabledit-input ' + settings.inputClass + '" name="' + settings.columns.editable[i][1] + '" style="display: none; width:auto;" disabled multiple >';
```

Into

```
var input = '<select class="multiSelect tabledit-input ' + settings.inputClass + '" name="' + settings.columns.editable[i][1] + '[]" style="display: none; width:auto;" disabled multiple >';
```